# Django project not rendering React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, react-native

In my project, I am trying to tie together Django and React.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> {% load static %}
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'logofavicon.ico' %}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{% static 'Banner.png' %}">
    <meta name="description" content="The future of digital content" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{% static 'logo192.png' %}" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'manifest.json' %}" />
    <title>Drop Party</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'index.js' %}"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "./styleguide.css";
import "./globals.css";

ReactDOM.render( <
    React.StrictMode >
    <
    App / >
    <
    /React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

settings.py

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/frontend/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    FRONTEND_DIR / 'build', FRONTEND_DIR / 'src', FRONTEND_DIR / 'public'
)
```

Project Hierarchy

[image: Project Hierarchy]

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694929/react-js-not-rendering-in-django-project), and confirmed that this solution is not applicable for me.

The primary issue, I think, is that Django is serving the html, but not running the .js, so I'm unsure of where to go with this.

I have also confirmed that the image linking is working as well, so I'm not getting 404 errors or anything like that.

Secondary, semi-related question: Should I be linking the favicons like this? I get the feeling I shouldn't be serving the html statically, but I was unable to find how exactly to serve the project, other than serving the html statically.

(edit) I have added in the script as in comments, but now I get an error where Django seems to reject the React tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML file has no `<script>` tag for your `index.js` (although, interestingly, it does have a `<noscript>`).

You need to tell your page about every JS file you want to run, which you do by using `<script>` tags.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script for more info.

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I have fixed the script issue, but now Django just does not recognize the react tags. I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on the React.strictmode line. Any ideas?

Comment: You should ask a new Stack Overflow question if you have a new (real) question, but the short answer is that you can't just use React's JSX language as if it were Javascript, so that error is saying "`<` isn't a legal character in Javascript".  You need to use the tools React provides: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 1):

Get `index.js` in the `public` folder.

Add the line below after `body` tag,

`<script src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I have fixed the script issue, but now Django just does not recognize the react tags. I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on the React.strictmode line. Any ideas?